# Get the id value of two different divs with the same class

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

Ok i am making a private message system and i have set php to echo a div with the same class but set the id = to the row ID, please examin the code below.

```
function Load()
{

$Connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "Data");
session_start();
$User = $_SESSION['Username'];
$Stats = 'SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE User="'.$User.'"';

if($Result = $Connect->query($Stats))
{
    while($Row = $Result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $From = $Row['FUser'];
        $Date = $Row['Date'];
        $Title = $Row['Title'];
        $ID = $Row['ID'];

        echo '<div id="'.$ID.'" class="String"><label class="TText" style="cursor:pointer;">From: ' . $From . ' - ' . $Date . ' - ' . $Title .'</label></div>';
    }
}
```

}

My JQuery:

```
$('.String').click(function()
{
    var Msg = $('#MMsg');
    var Back = $('#Back');
    var Str = $('.String');
    Str.fadeOut('fast', function()
    {
        Msg.fadeIn('fast');
        Back.fadeIn('fast');
        var ID = $('.String').attr('id');

        $.ajax
        ({
            url:'MLoad.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:{ID:ID},
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(MText)
            {
                $('#MMBox').html(MText.T);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

when I alert the var ID i get the same result for both divs but in the html the ID is different for each.  i.e the alert boxes both give me the first ID each time.

Answer (score 3):

Use $(this) to get the ID of the element fadeOut is being applied to. Otherwise you're only getting the ID of the first matching div.

var ID = $(this).attr('id');

Answer (score 0):

When you're in the click function `this` refers to the item that was clicked. So you can use `$(this).attr('id')` to retrieve the ID of the `.String` that was clicked.

```
$('.String').click(function()
{
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var Msg = $('#MMsg');
    var Back = $('#Back');
    var Str = $('.String');
    Str.fadeOut('fast', function()
    {
        Msg.fadeIn('fast');
        Back.fadeIn('fast');

        $.ajax
        ({
            url:'MLoad.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:{ID:id},
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(MText)
            {
                $('#MMBox').html(MText.T);
            }
        });
    });
});
```